# RabbitMQ – Cancel consumer.nextDelivery while it's waiting for a response

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

Is it possible with the RabbitMQ amqp-client library to cancel a `nextDelivery`? I have a thread that has already called `consumer.nextDelivery()`, and this call is waiting for a response from the queue. What I want is to stop this from another thread. `channel.basicCancel` will cancel only after the current `nextDelivery` call has returned, which is not exactly what I want, because the application is in a state where it can't do anything with the received delivery.

I've been searching for a solution to this for a while, and I'm at the point where I think I'm misunderstanding something about RabbitMQ, because I get no search results that match my problem.

Comment: Why don't you just return the message back again into the queue after returning from `nextDelivery()`?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad the queue stores an ordered sequence of events, I'm not sure that would work. Maybe an alternative approach would be to do manual ack, and not ack the delivery I can't handle?

Comment: But then again... if the queue is empty it might take a while until I get a response. I'm looking for a clean shutdown solution.

Comment: So, you receive the message in any case but may not be able to process it? Are message receival and message treatment clearly separated in your process?

Comment: @fge yes to both questions.

Comment: OK, so, what do you want to achieve? If the processing part is unable to operate, tell the receiving part to stop receiving and "unreceive" messages? That is quite tricky... Why don't you just merge receive/handle? Shut down your executor, no new jobs can be submitted; as to tasks already in progress, they will proceed until done. No?

Comment: did you solve this? I nned to know.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to stop this from another thread

Personal advice: don't do it.

From the information gathered in the comments, it appears that you are separating the message receival from its treatment. My suggestion is to *merge* both; and use an `ExecutorService` to wrap them both.

When you need to shut the whole thing down, call `.shutDown()` on the `ExecutorService`: it means that no other task can be submitted to that execution.

As the receival/treatment process is now merged, it means you can never have a state in which a message is received but cannot be treated anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work but try to use `shutdownNow()` of `ExecutorService`:

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

```
executor.submit(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // ...
        Message m = consumer.nextDelivery();
        // ...
    }
});
```

```
executor.shutdownNow();
```

---

[ShutdownNow()'s javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) states:

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of
>   waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting
>   execution. This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to
>   terminate. Use awaitTermination to do that.
>
> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing
>   actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will
>   cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to
>   interrupts may never terminate.